# NSpredicate Results

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary, nspredicate, multidimensional-array

I have array compose of 2 dictionaries . The first dictionary is grouped by **Services** and gives me the numbers of Companies that has the same service in a array containing my second dictionary with all the details .

The first dictionary has 2 keys **Companies and Services**.

Within the Companies I have an Array  containing my second dictionary with following  key values

**AddressInformation , Name and Service** .

I want NSpredicate to eliminate all the **companie names** 
objects from my second dictionary that does not correspond to searchText . Now its filtering process takes place only at the first dictionary. It keeps giving me all the results from my second dictionary but eliminates only the objects of the first dictionary (Companies and Services) .

Thank in advance !

> ```
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@",
>                               @"Companies",@"Name",searchText];
>
>     FilteredObject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[AllDataGroupbyServiceArray
> ```
>
> filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

```
(
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = h3k2w3;
            Name = Teg;
            Service = "";
        }
    );
    Services = "";
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = j9g2k6;
            Name = Megan;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2t3b3;
            Name = Janet;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "J4J 1H7";
            Name = Rick;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "H1T 4B6";
            Name = Herber;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "J0K 3B0";
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = canada;
            Service = Electrician;
        }
    );
    Services = Electrician;
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = J0L2K0;
            Name = "Colas Bn";
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5A1M2;
            Name = mrnoskill2;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J0L2K0;
            Name = test8;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5C1S3;
            Name = test6;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h3r1z2;
            Name = Jason;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = j7h2k7;
            Name = max;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5Z2W5;
            Name = Fred;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "H4G 1K6";
            Name = Joe;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = j3y7a6;
            Name = Tets;
            Service = Mason;
        }
    );
    Services = Mason;
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = jake;
            Service = Plumber;
        }
    );
    Services = Plumber;
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `predicateWithFormat:`, try `predicateWithBlock:`. This gives you complete control of the procedure used for testing each entry.

Also I would suggest that your model is weird. You might need a more congenial structure for your data model.